# Django delete record using modal

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I'm new in Django and i like to implement a Modal to delete records. The problem is a funny error in the modal form because is expecting a parameter. The modal link has this

but I don't know how add the right parameter.
This is my List in html

```
<table id="tablaAlmacenes" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Almacén</th>
                          <th>Detalles</th>
                          <th></th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>                                     
                          {% for almacen in object_list %}
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ almacen.almacen }}</td>
                            <td>{{ almacen.descripcion }}</td>
                            <td>
                              <div>
                                 <a href="" class="btn btn-link text-info">Detalles</a>                                  
                                 <a a href="" class="btn btn-link text-primary">Editar</a>
                                  <a class="btn btn-link deleteAlmacen" data-id="{{ almacen.id}}"><span class="fas fa-trash text-danger"></a>
                              </div>
                           </td>
                          </tr>
                          {% endfor %}                        
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Almacén</th>
                          <th>Detalles</th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                  </table>
```

this is my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('polls.urls'),name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('contact/',views.contact, name='contacto')
    path('almacenes/', AlmacenesListView.as_view(), name='almacenes'),
    path('almacenes/nuevo', AlmacenesCreateView.as_view(), name='crear_almacen'),
    path('almacenes/<int:id>/remove/', AlmacenesDeleteView.as_view(), name='eliminar_almacen')
]
```

This is my views.py

```
class AlmacenesListView(ListView):
    model = Almacen
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'

    success_message = "Bien!!!!"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = "Lista de Almacenes"
        print(reverse_lazy('almacenes'))
        return context

class AlmacenesCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Almacen
    form_class = AlmacenesForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('almacenes')
    success_message = "Bien!!!!"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        return context
    
class AlmacenesDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Almacen
    success_url = reverse_lazy('almacenes')
```

and my modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" aria-modal="false" id="deleteAlmacenModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmación</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>¿Desea eliminar el Almacen?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <form action="{% url 'eliminar_almacen' (some parameter here but error) %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="almacen_id"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

scrpt for modal

```
    $(document).on('click','.deleteAlmacen',function(){
    var id_almacen=$(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#almacen_id').val(id_almacen);
    $('#deleteAlmacenModal').modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: Does the modal pop up when you click on it?

Comment: The modals it's show, but only if I add a parameter to the url like `{% url 'eliminar_almacen' 4 %}`, however this doesn't work because throw me an 405 error. Also if I don't add a parameter in URl, show's me an error **Reverse for 'eliminar_almacen' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['almacenes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/\\Z']**. The detail is I'm setting the **almacen.id** in this scritp sentence `$('#almacen_id').val(id_almacen);` and the hidden input in the modal have it, but how can I give to the URL parameter? Thanks for your comment

Comment: Something like this `<form action="{% url 'eliminar_almacen' %}"  method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="almacen_id"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
        </form>` but throw me an error about the URL parameter. thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you are using bootstrap you don't need to trigger the modal with jquery but let bootstrap do the magic.
Your code should be something like that:
html:

```
<table id="tablaAlmacenes" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Almacén</th>
                      <th>Detalles</th>
                      <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>                                     
                      {% for almacen in object_list %}
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ almacen.almacen }}</td>
                        <td>{{ almacen.descripcion }}</td>
                        <td>
                          <div>
                             <a href="" class="btn btn-link text-info">Detalles</a>                                  
                             <a a href="" class="btn btn-link text-primary">Editar</a>
                              <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteAlmacenModal{{almacen.id}}""><span class="fas fa-trash text-danger"></a> <!-- data-toggle and data-target work in bootstrap4, in 5 is data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle -->
                         {% include 'yourtemplatefolder/modals/delete_almacen_modal.html' %} <!-- as best practice create another folder called modals and put there you modal.html files, as in this case and include them in your code -->  
                          </div>
                       </td>
                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}                        
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Almacén</th>
                      <th>Detalles</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
              </table>
```

Now, being the modal called inside the for loop, you can fix your modal like this:
delete_almacen_modal.html

```
    <div class="modal fade" aria-modal="false" id="deleteAlmacenModal{{almacen.id}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmación</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>¿Desea eliminar el Almacen?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <form action="{% url 'eliminar_almacen' pk=almacen.id %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="id" id="almacen_id"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Now that should work.

Comment: If I set that shows me an error like **Reverse for 'eliminar_almacen' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['almacenes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/\\Z']** because the modal is not under table enviroment for says something. it's called by script function. I set the valie of the id in the variable `var id_almacen=$(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#almacen_id').val(id_almacen);` of the script code, but I don't how to add it to URL parameter

Comment: I completely modified my answer, let me know if that works

Comment: thanks for comment! I do that with JQuery because using exaclty your code, delete always the first record, not the selected record, no matters if I select one of the middle or the last. This is a solution that I found years ago using Laravel, I'm translating to Django because I'm studying. There is another ways to do it, but I would like try this one!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one piece of code. You should add {{almacen.id}} in your id one the modal and the url. You can see the code edited now.